# Assign character to unique strings in each column and reset value to that character

Tags: arrays, pandas, string, sorting

I have a large pandas dataframe made up of strings:

```
  col1   col2         col3
0 'If', 'albatross', 'boss'
1 'If', 'boot',      'god'
2 'If', 'chicken',   'alive'
3 'If', 'chicken',   'dead'
```

I want to alphabetically order the unique words in each position and assign to each a symbol (A,B,C,...)  (for example boss-B god-D alive-A dead-C) such that, if three different strings appear in the texts, then the symbols A,B, and C take their place in the dataframe. In this case we get:

```
     col1  col2 col3
   0  'A', 'A', 'B'
   1  'A', 'B', 'D'
   2  'A', 'C', 'A'
   3  'A', 'C', 'C'
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this for very large datasets? (I am trying to turn long scripts (like BIBLE long) into pseudogenetic data that can be fed into phylogenetics programmes)

So far I've managed to create lists of alphabetically ordered unique strings (the list e) and the letters (the list sym):
import string

```
sym=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
e=[]
for i in data.columns:
    c=sorted(data[i].unique(),key=str.lower)
    e.append(c)
```

I am struggling with switching the strings in the data frame to the corresponding letters. I have tried:

```
for i in data.columns:
    for j in e:
        for k in range(len(j)):
            data.loc[data[i] == j[k], i] = sym[k]
```

This is extremely slow but seems to work well. For large datasets (even a under a thousand words) it takes forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) all the columns then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) the indices to the [`uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) letters :

```
upl = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 1))

out = data.rank(method="dense").map(lambda v: upl[v]) # or `applymap` if <2.1.0

# a variant : `out = data.rank(method="dense").apply(lambda s: s.map(upl))`
```

Or, as suggested by @mozway :

```
out = (pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(ascii_uppercase))
      [data.rank(method="dense").astype(int)-1], columns=data.columns))
```

Alternatively, using a dense [`rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) with [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) :

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
from string import ascii_uppercase

ind = rankdata(data, axis=0, method="dense") - 1
upl = np.vectorize(lambda x: ascii_uppercase[x])(ind)
out = pd.DataFrame(upl, columns=data.columns)

# 140 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  col1 col2 col3
0    A    A    B
1    A    B    D
2    A    C    A
3    A    C    C

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Used input :

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['If', 'If', 'If', 'If'],
 'col2': ['albatross', 'boot', 'chicken', 'chicken'],
 'col3': ['boss', 'god', 'alive', 'dead']})
```

Perfplot (*~100K rows*) :

[image]

Comment: You can also index directly with numpy: `np.array(list(ascii_uppercase))[data.rank(method="dense").astype(int)-1]`

Comment: @mozway, you're the master of indexing ;) I included your solution in the answer.